# What permissions is my github PAT missing?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm triggering a github action using a webhook. Until recently this worked perfectly but I got a request from Github to refresh my PAT to the new format and now I get a permission denied error. Am I missing a permission or has the authorization syntax changed?

This is the webhook I'm calling:

```
curl -d '{"ref":"v2.0","inputs":{"oga_no":"1369"}}' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' -H 'Authorization: Basic ghp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' -X POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/ogauk/boatregister/actions/workflows/publish.yml/dispatches'
```

And this is the response:

```
{
  "message": "Must have admin rights to Repository.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event"
}
```

Comment: It may not be related to the PAT scope (even if you set `repo` permissions) but at the account scope. Does the account have admin permissions on this repository?

Comment: @GuiFalourd - thanks. It did before and I haven't changed anything but maybe a GitHub policy change? Any idea what I should check?

Comment: There is a new `workflow` permission for github action on the PAT scope list. Did you use it in this token?

Comment: yes - repo & workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Something must have changed with the new token format. I spotted a [post](https://www.techiediaries.com/github-actions-workflow-manual-http-post-triggers-workflow_dispatch-repository_dispatch/) with a slightly different syntax and tried it.

```
curl -d '{"ref":"v2.0","inputs":{"oga_no":"1369"}}' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' -H 'Authorization: token ghp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' -X POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/ogauk/boatregister/actions/workflows/publish.yml/dispatches'
```

So changing Basic to token fixed my problem.

Comment: You resolved it just by modifying the `Authorization` header using `token` instead of `basic` ?

Comment: just that! Would not have guessed than in a million years.